# Magento 1.9.3.7 the session id is too long or contains illegal characters

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, log

Looking at my log files: specifically the system.log file; I can see multiple entries of the following:

> The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid
>   characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 134

Rather strange, as I am using a pretty default setup of the magento version 1.9.3.7.

Looking online I cannot see anyone has faced this issue or fix. Was wondering if anyone could help identify the cause or fix to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not worry about that. That can be completely random where person with old session was trying to access your site.

Comment: Much appreciated. I will not worry too much.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started seeing these and this could be someone trying to expose PHP warnings.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are
See also https://www.owasp.org/index.php?title=Full_Path_Disclosure

Ensure PHP Error Reporting is **turned off** on the server
error_reporting(0);

Ensure display errors in **index.php** is commented out
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: That's rather worrying information. Display errors is rightly turned off. Surely magento would have negated this issue?

Comment: You can test yourself by altering the Frontend Session Cookie. The first time I noticed this was at the beginning of December 2017 therefore Magento may correct in a future release.  However, I agree, it seems to me such a fundamental error not to check that a string contains only what you want it to!! The 2nd link above dates from 2012 so it's a known issue.

Comment: I see the error once every so often. Not too frequently

Answer (score -1):

I keep receiving a lot of this messages but that's because I test my website against all sorts of threats. Each time you get this error means somebody or something is trying to disclose sensitive information from your website. This is Session Hijacking form of attack a type of MITM (man in the middle) attack

- The problem is Magento as default send both unsecured (HTTP) cookies and secured (HTTPS) to the website even if you use only HTTPS
- To limit possibility of you site getting hacked make sure you setting "use HTTP only" cookie is set to yes in (System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management) in this way cookies on your website cannot be manipulated via client-side code like JavaScript

Fix - Install this extension https://github.com/lukanetconsult/mage-secure-cookie
Enjoy :)